# Not getting the desired result with for loop in R for required conditions

Tags: r

The `Result` field should contain (Sum of Mod values for a STATE where category not equal to 0). Remaining values should be 0.

I am trying to achieve the same using for loop but not getting the desired result. Appreciate your help in getting this resolved.

Here is some `SampleData`

```
    State  Category        Mod       Result
1       A      0            5            45           
2       A      1            10           0
3       A      2            15           0
4       A      3            10           0
5       A      4            10           0
6       B      0            11           60
7       B      1            12           0
8       B      2            14           0
9       B      3            16           0
10      B      4            18           0
```

This is what I am trying via for loop:

```
for(i in SampleData) {
  SampleData$Result[i] <- ifelse(SampleData$Category[i] == "0", 
                          sum(SampleData$Mod[i:i+5]), 
                          0)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dplyr version, if you like:

```r
library(dplyr)

SampleData <- data_frame(State = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
                         Category = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), 
                         Mod = c(5L, 10L, 15L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 18L))

SampleData %>% 
    group_by(State) %>% 
    mutate(Result = ifelse(Category == 0, sum(Mod[-1]), 0))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#> # Groups:   State [2]
#>    State Category   Mod Result
#>    <chr>    <int> <int>  <dbl>
#>  1 A            0     5     45
#>  2 A            1    10      0
#>  3 A            2    15      0
#>  4 A            3    10      0
#>  5 A            4    10      0
#>  6 B            0    11     60
#>  7 B            1    12      0
#>  8 B            2    14      0
#>  9 B            3    16      0
#> 10 B            4    18      0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
transform(df, Result = ifelse(Category == 0,
                              ave(Mod, State, FUN = function(x) sum(x) - x[Category == 0]),
                              0))
#   State Category Mod Result
#1      A        0   5     45
#2      A        1  10      0
#3      A        2  15      0
#4      A        3  10      0
#5      A        4  10      0
#6      B        0  11     60
#7      B        1  12      0
#8      B        2  14      0
#9      B        3  16      0
#10     B        4  18      0
```

`ave(Mod, State, FUN = function(x) sum(x) - x[Category == 0])` calculates the sum of `Mod` for each value of `State` and subtracts the respective value of `Mod` where `Category == 0` is `TRUE`.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(State = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B"), Category = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L
), Mod = c(5L, 10L, 15L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 18L)), .Names = c("State", 
"Category", "Mod"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```